# Python : Creating a socket in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I am trying to create a socket **IN A THREAD**, but i am unable to do so.
My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import threading
import socket

class test1():
    def serve(self):
        host = ''
        port = 9999
        th_obj = threading.Thread(target = self.thread_method, args = (host,port))
        th_obj.daemon = True
        th_obj.start()

    def thread_method(self,host,port):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        sock.bind(('',9999))
        sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            connection, addr = sock.accept()
            connection.settimeout(60)
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(2048)
                t = open('file.txt', 'a')
                t.write(data)

test1().serve()
```

The problem is the script won't when I set `daemon  = True` while it is working perfectly without it.

How can i solve this problem. It is essential to me to demonize it.

Comment: I don't think you want `daemon = True`, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html): `A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left`

Comment: @syntonym, it is highly important for my task that the socket runs in the backend. That's why i needed daemon=True. is there any other way to achieve the same functionality???

Comment: What do you man with "runs in the backend"?

Comment: I suspect you mean "runs in the background". In which case you need to `fork` a new process. Probably you should be using the `multiprocessing` module rather than `threading`